# Set a default filtering from a query

Tags: powerbi

I already setup my report and filters, everything works fine.
What I'm missing is to be able to set the default values of a filter based on the top result of a query (it will return the latest release of a product list).

I don't see any option in the filters to do this, neither on slicers, so I don't know if this is even possible.